# How to remove all traces of a program

Tags: windows

One thing that annoys me with uninstallers is they don't undo every change they make in a computer. One program I had created a new user and didn't bother deleting the user or even letting me know I had to do it manually.

Other programs create folders in %AppData% and other folders that aren't removed. I get that one might want to install later and keep the same settings, but I hate that most don't bother.

Is there a simply way (not just Windows Search) to delete every change an installer / program makes? Is there some kind of reverse-engineer installer that checks changes and deletes them again?

Comment: There are uninstallers which traces installation process and revert it fully. But revert all changes made while program executind... I have not seen such. *Is there a simply way (not just Windows Search) to delete every change an installer / program makes?* Of course. Backup before and full restore including re-formatting after.

Comment: That's very true, I've never actually tried, does windows create a full backup, documents and everything before the restore or is it a list of changes made before and after?